# How do you unlock an Active Directory account on a different domain using PowerShell 2.0?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I found an amazing PowerShell script by LazyWinAdmin that kind of does what I want - but it is limited to just the current domain. The way our network is set up we have different domains for certain types of accounts.

I am trying to write up a script that simply unlocks a specified user account on a specific domain. Our system uses PowerShell 2.0 which is making this very difficult because I know that the later versions have Active Directory management cmdlets. Trust me, I have requested that we have a newer version of PowerShell installed on our systems but the company flat out refuses to budge.

I feel kind of stupid because I have worked almost exclusively with the newer versions in the past so I got used to the various cmdlets rather than having to manually draft out every single thing I want to do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you have any draft code that attempts this goal so far that you can post? If so, please edit that into your question.

Comment: To be absolutely fair, I have been repurposing the LazyWindAdmin script as that is the closest to what I am trying to do. 

$Searcher = [ADSISearcher]"(sAMAccountName=$Name)"
$Results = $Searcher.FindOne()

Comment: In that case, it's probably best to edit in the current source, modifications and all.

Comment: I have added it to my original post. Thank you for your help, Mr. Tuggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the search root to search from other domain.

Original code in $buttonUnlock_Click:

```
# Search for this account in the current domain
$Searcher = [ADSISearcher]"(sAMAccountName=$Name)"
$Results = $Searcher.FindOne()
```

Also in $buttonCheck_Click (it has no search code but just a comment):

```
# Search for this account in the current domain
```

Change both to:

```
$searcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$searcher.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=$name)"
$searcher.SearchRoot = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry('LDAP://other.domain', 'user', 'pwd')
$results = $searcher.FindOne()
```

If current user already has permission to access the other domains, you may simply put `[adsi]'LDAP://other.domain'` as search root.

Comment: Ok, I have tried this. While it is running correctly, it's not finding any of the users I specify. I know that the LDAP://other.domain that I specified is correct.. it's just not finding the users that I am searching for.

Comment: The $buttonCheck_Click has no code to do any search. Please put the above code to both $buttonUnlock_Click and $buttonCheck_Click.

Comment: Updated the answer, please check.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that as well! I just added it in there and it worked flawlessly. Thank you so much for your help! I also realized that I had a book dedicated to this specific type of administrating collecting dust on my shelf. After look through it I found the same results. All is working well now! Thank you so much! :)